# Set timeout on a thread from thread pool executor

Tags: java, spring-boot

The question itself says it all. I know how to create a thread pool executor and start Async on the given thread pool executor but what i would like to know is there any way to set different time outs for different threads?

Example :

```
@Async("thread pool executor") Func1

@Async("thread pool executor") Func2
```

If yes, how do i achieve it?

I want the time out of the first one to be 7 second and the second one to be 1 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one way to set the time on `Future` object but not on the `ThreadPool`, But you can't set it at thread level , still you can set it at task level (because there is no guarantee which thread is going to execute the task)

**Example**

```
@Async("someExecutor")
public Future<String> asyncService() {

    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("start").thenApply(s->{

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - "+Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup());
        return "hello";
    });     
}
```

get `Future`

```
Future<String> result = asyncService.asyncService();
    result.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: programer need to handle while using `get()` but still there is `exceptionally()` optional that can be executed in exception case https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#exceptionally-java.util.function.Function- @BOTJr.

Comment: Yes since they are calling Future.get() on main method

Comment: Yes. That would defeat my whole purpose right?.. I. Mean i would call func1 in some sort of loop for different values and i would like them to end after a certain time out. If I do this wayyy, i will have to wait..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185332/discussion-between-deadpool-and-botjr).